# Elastica query term not return results

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

```
 $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.site.search');

$boolQuery_term = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();                    
$term = new \Elastica_Query_Terms();
$term->setTerms('CmpCode', array(1,2,3));
$boolQuery_term->addMust($term);

Path: site/search/_search
Method: GET
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"CmpCode":[1,2,3]}}]}}]}},"from":0,"size":25}
Time: 3.05 ms
```

Query not return results.

Config:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        site:
            settings:
                index:
                     analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            my_analyzer:
                                type: snowball
                                tokenizer: my_tokinizer
                                filter   : [lowercase, my_ngram]
                        filter:
                            my_ngram:
                                type: "nGram"
                                min_gram: 3
                                max_gram: 50
                        tokenizer:
                            my_tokinizer:
                                type: "nGram"
                                min_gram: 3
                                max_gram: 50
            types:
                search:
                    mappings:
                        cmpName:
                        CitName:
                        CatName:
                        cmpAddress:
                        cmpSite:
                        cmpEmail:
                        cmpCeo:
                        cmpCode: {type: integer}
                        cmpVat:
                        cmpAddress:
                        cmpEmp: {type: integer}
                        cmpReturn: {type: integer}
                        cmpReturnFrom:
                        cmpReturnTill:
                    persistence:
                        identifier: cmpId
                        driver: orm
                        model: Catalog\WebBundle\Entity\ComCompany
                        provider:
                        finder:
```

Query nor return results, in db exist record with id "`1`, `2`, `3`", where can be problem ?

Where can be probelm ?

Comment: looks like it _must_ have all terms, e.g there must be an entity with cmpCode == array(1,2,3)   ...is this what you expect ? Maybe youre looking for TermsFilter

Comment: Try passing one value only to test.